# Proving that $(u+v)×w=u×w+v×w$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's $$(\overrightarrow{u}+\overrightarrow{v})\times\overrightarrow{w}=\overrightarrow{u}\times\overrightarrow{w}+\overrightarrow{v}\times\overrightarrow{w}$$ How to prove it?

**Update:** The problem is that I don't know how to do it because I don't know the number of dimensions. Is there a general formula?

Comment: How about writing out the components of the vectors $\vec{u}, \vec{v}, \vec{w}$ and computing each side?

Comment: How are you defining the cross product here? Are you in three dimensions? What have you tried (like applying the definition)? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @MichaelJoyce I don't know how to do it because I don't know the number of dimensions. Is there a general formula?

Comment: Surely this indicates the usual $3$-dimensional cross product. (That said, this is true for any cross product in the sense of Brown \& Gray, which by hypothesis is bilinear.)

Comment: There are several ways to define the cross product of two vectors in a 3-dimensional inner product space. They are all equivalent, but if you really want a proof of this particular consequence, you need to declare which definition you mean. So according to your sources, what is the _definition_ of $\vec{u}\times\vec{w}$ in the first place?

Comment: @alex.jordan This is all I have.

Comment: If you don't know the number of dimensions, how do you expect *us* to know the number of dimensions?  This sounds like a question of clarification that you should ask your instructor.  (That said, the cross product is normally only defined for vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$, so that's probably a pretty safe assumption.  If you don't know the definition of cross product in $\mathbb{R}^3$, you'll surely need to look it up to construct a proof.)

Comment: If the vectors $u$, $v$ and $w$ are three dimensional, perhaps you can use the matrix multiplication form of cross product (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Conversion_to_matrix_multiplication) to prove the identity you asked.

Comment: What *do* you know about $\vec a\times\vec b$? I'm sure it's more than "there is an operation $\times$ that takes two vectors and gives a vector" (which wouldn't be sufficient to prove that equation anyway). On the other hand, that equation seems not to be among what you were told about it (or otherwise asking to prove it would be pointless).

Answer (score 1):

This property should do it. Let $u,v,w\in V$ (where we take $V$ a presumably three dimensional inner product space). Let $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ be the inner product on $V$. Then $$\langle u,v\times w\rangle =\det[u,v,w]_{\mathcal B}$$

Where $\det[\,]_{\mathcal B}$ denotes the determinant of the matrix formed by $u,v,w$ in an orthonormal basis $\mathcal B = \{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$.

In this light let, $\gamma_1$ be the first coordinate of $\gamma = (a+b)\times w$. Then, $$\gamma_1 = \langle e_1,(a+b)\times w\rangle = \det[e_1,a+b,w] = \det[e_1,a,w] + \det[e_1,b,w] =  \\ =  \langle e_1,a\times w\rangle + \langle e_1, b\times w\rangle$$

Idem for $\gamma_2,\gamma_3$. Can you take it from here?

P.S. Take $\mathbb R^3$ with the usual scalar product if the notation here clouds things up.

Answer (score 0):

The cross-product is defined by $(u\times v)_k = \epsilon^{ijk} u_i v_j$, where the $\epsilon^{ijk}$ are certain constants. (Here, $\epsilon^{ijk}$ is the Levi-Civita symbol and can be defined in various equivalent ways, but it doesn't matter; we just care that $\epsilon^{ijk}$ is a constant, independent of $u$ and $v$. Also, I'm adopting the Einstein convention of implicitly summing over repeated indices.) Each component $(u\times v)_k$ is linear in the $u_i$ and $v_j$, which means that $u\times v$ is linear in $u$ and $v$.

Answer (score -2):

The cross product is defined on two vectors of three dimensions as: $$\vec a \times \vec b =\begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\a_2\\a_3\end{bmatrix}\times \begin{bmatrix} b_1 \\b_2\\b_3 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a_2b_3-b_3a_2 \\a_3b_1-a_1b_3\\a_1b_2-b_2a_1 \end{bmatrix}$$

The sum of two three-dimensional vectors is:
$$\vec c + \vec d =\begin{bmatrix} c_1 \\c_2\\c_3\end{bmatrix}+ \begin{bmatrix} d_1 \\d_2\\d_3 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} c_1+d_1 \\c_2+d_2\\c_3+d_3 \end{bmatrix}$$

Use this to show that: $$(\vec u+\vec v)\times \vec w = (\vec u\times \vec w)+(\vec v\times \vec w)$$